# Python: Parsing dictionary data based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that prints out pull requests to the console if the labels 'ready-to-merge' and 'Validation Succeeded' are applied to them.

I would also like to go through these same pull requests to print 'True' if any file in the set of files associated with the pull request have the value of 'status':'added'.

The code I have below prints out results for each individual file, but I would like it to only print one line if the 'added' condition is met in any of the files associated with File Status: True, else File Status: False if none of the files in the set have 'status':'added'.

I tried to use the same logic I used for outputting the title of the pull request if the labels condition is met, but it's not working

I hope this makes sense.

The output I'm getting now:

```
Title: updates for blah
Files Status: False
Files Status: False
Files Status: True
Title: updates2
Files Status: False
Files Status: False
```

The output I would like based on these results:

```
Title: updates for blah
File Status: True
Title: updates2
File Status: False
```

Code:

```
for prs in repo.pull_requests():
        getlabels = repo.issue(prs.number).as_dict()

        if 'ready-to-merge' in [getlabels['name'] for getlabels in getlabels['labels']] and 'Validation Succeeded' in [getlabels['name'] for getlabels in getlabels['labels']]:
            changes = repo.pull_request(prs.number).as_dict()
            print("Title: ",changes['title'])

            for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():
                files = data.as_dict()
                if 'added' in [files['status'] for status in files]:
                    print("File Status: True")
                else:
                    print("File Status: False")
```

Sample data returned when iterating through the files associated with a pull request.  I'm looking to build the conditions based on "status": "added":

```
[
  {
    "sha": "bbcd538c8e72b8c175046e27cc8f907076331401",
    "filename": "file1.txt",
    "status": "added",
    "additions": 103,
    "deletions": 21,
    "changes": 124,
    "blob_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/blob/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e/file1.txt",
    "raw_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/raw/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e/file1.txt",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/file1.txt?ref=6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "patch": "@@ -132,7 +132,7 @@ module Test @@ -1000,7 +1000,7 @@ module Test"
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't know what `files` contains exactly, but this `[files['status'] for status in files]` seems wrong. Maybe you wanted to do `[file[status] for file in files]` ?

Comment: @rantanplan. I added sample json output of the contents of files.  Also, I modified the code based on your feedback, but now I receive the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: I figured it out by changing the code to, `if 'added' in (data.status for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files())`.  I didn't need to convert it to dictionary content first.  I used `data.status` and put the `for` loop inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad it works.

Comment: Glad you found a solution for your problem. Your question still shows up in the list of questions that need answering. Could you write an answer to your question, showing what you changed, and accept it? Mind that answering your own question is actively encouraged by SO.